# Does for loop take multiple arguments in python?

Tags: python

See the following code :

```
choices = ['pizza', 'pasta', 'salad', 'nachos']
print 'Your choices are:'
for index, item in enumerate(choices):
    print index+1, item
```

Output:

```
Your choices are:
1 pizza
2 pasta
3 salad
4 nachos
None
```

In the third line, **for takes two arguments.**

**for index, item in enumerate(choices):**

But the syntax of for loop is:

```
array=[...]
for element in array
```

*How does this actually work?
Does for loop take in multiple arguments? If yes, how can we use them?*

Comment: What you're looping over can return more than one item which can be unpacked... have you read http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate ? (on an aide - it'd be easier to just use enumerate(choices, 1)` instead of keep adding 1)

Comment: This is called [**sequence unpacking**](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences).

Comment: The syntax of the `for` loop is actually `for things in otherThings`, not `for elem in array`: http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#for

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python lets you *unpack* sequences on assignment:

```
>>> foo = ('spam', 'ham')
>>> bar, baz = foo
>>> bar
'spam'
>>> baz
'ham'
```

The same can be done in a `for` loop:

```
list_of_tuples = [('foo', 'bar'), ('spam', 'ham')]
for value1, value2 in list_of_tuples:
    print value1, value2
```

would print

```
foo bar
spam ham
```

The `enumerate()` function produces tuples of two values, the index, and value from the sequence passed in as an argument:

```
>>> seasons = ['Spring', 'Summer', 'Fall', 'Winter']
>>> list(enumerate(seasons))
[(0, 'Spring'), (1, 'Summer'), (2, 'Fall'), (3, 'Winter')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it takes one argument, of type tuple, which is then **unpacked**.

The syntax is similar to the following:

```
a, b = b, a
```

which is a nice way of writing a "swap" of the two variables.

However, think of it as

```
(a,b) = (b,a)
```

Then you have a "single tuple" assignment, combined with **tuple unpacking**.

Answer (score 0):

It's tuple unpacking. In an assignment, you can put a tuple of variables on the left side and if the right side has exactly that amount of elements, they get assigned like that:

```
a, b = (3, 4)  # Now a is 3 and b is 4
```

You can do that in for loops as well

```
for a, b in [(3, 4), (5, 6)]:
    print(a)
```

will print 3 and then 5.

Since enumerate yields tuples of (index, element), the for loop in your element works.